# Pandas: If statments with multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out a way to write an if statement based on a couple criteria. I have a large CSV file that I have cleaned and already organized. There are a couple things I need to do:
[image]

I first need a way that will check to see if the machine is "on" for more than 3 rows. If that is true then I need to get its corredsponding pressure for that cycle and find the average of it. For example, in the df aboce, in rows 14-19 the machine is on for more than 3 rows so then I need to get the average pressure across all instances in this period.

This data contains 40,000 rows, so I will then need this to cycle through the entire sheet to keep track of the total number of times the machine is on, and each corresponding average pressure.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

header_list = ['Time']
df = pd.read_csv('S8-1.csv' , skiprows=6 , names = header_list)

#splits the data into proper columns
df[['Date/Time','Pressure']] = df.Time.str.split(",,", expand=True)

#deletes orginal messy column
df.pop('Time')

#convert Pressure from object to numeric
df['Pressure'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Pressure'], errors = 'coerce')

#converts to a time
df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f' , errors = 'coerce')

df['Moving Average'] = df['Pressure'].rolling(window=5).mean()
df['Rolling Average Center']= df['Pressure'].rolling(window=5, center=True).mean()
df['Machine On/Off'] = ['1' if x >= 115 else '0' for x in df['Rolling Average Center'] ]

arr = df['Machine On/Off']

def find_runs(x):
    x = np.asanyarray(x)
    if x.ndim !=1:
        raise Valueerror('Only 1D array supported')
    n = x.shape[0]

    if n == 0:
        return np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([])
    
    else:
        loc_run_start = np.empty(n, dtype=bool)
        loc_run_start[0] = True
        np.not_equal(x[:-1], x[1:], out=loc_run_start[1:])
        run_starts = np.nonzero(loc_run_start)[0]

        # find run values
        run_values = x[loc_run_start]

        # find run lengths
        run_lengths = np.diff(np.append(run_starts, n))
        
        return run_values, run_starts, run_lengths

run = find_runs(arr)

df.iloc[_start:run_length]['whatever column']
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in plain text (no image).

Answer (score 0):

Suggested first step: make new column with ones and zeros... 1 for on, 0 for off.

```
df['newcolumnname'] = 0

df['newcolumnname'][df['machine on/off'] == 'on'] = 1
```

Grab that column as a numpy array:

```
arr = df['newcolumnname'].to_numpy()
```

Then using the following code credit: https://gist.github.com/alimanfoo/c5977e87111abe8127453b21204c1065

```
import numpy as np


def find_runs(x):
    """Find runs of consecutive items in an array."""

    # ensure array
    x = np.asanyarray(x)
    if x.ndim != 1:
        raise ValueError('only 1D array supported')
    n = x.shape[0]

    # handle empty array
    if n == 0:
        return np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([])

    else:
        # find run starts
        loc_run_start = np.empty(n, dtype=bool)
        loc_run_start[0] = True
        np.not_equal(x[:-1], x[1:], out=loc_run_start[1:])
        run_starts = np.nonzero(loc_run_start)[0]

        # find run values
        run_values = x[loc_run_start]

        # find run lengths
        run_lengths = np.diff(np.append(run_starts, n))

        return run_values, run_starts, run_lengths
```

get the "runs"...should only have zeros and ones.

```
run_values, run_starts, run_lengths = find_runs(arr)

print(run_values) #just to see what order they are in
print(run_starts.shape)#get an idea of the shapes
print(run_lengths.shape)

_ix = run_values.tolist().index(1)
```

To get data from your pandas,

```
for _start, _run_length in zip(run_starts[_ix], run_lengths[_ix]):
    tmp_df = df.iloc[_start:_start+_run_length]
    #do what you want
    print(tmp_df)
    break #remove this...I just don't know how big your data is
```

You're correct when you are thinking "this answer does not run".  But it should give you enough to get going and solve your problem.
Incomplete question gets an incomplete response.

TODO:  make your machine on/off to be integer...not sure if it is absolutely needed, but if it's a numerical numpy array then there are more options available to you.

```
df['Machine On/Off'] = [1 if x >= 115 else 0 for x in df['Rolling Average Center'] ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry i am new to coding, i am getting an error that the df.iloc isnt there? Any suggestions how to fix this. I pasted the code above

Comment: the variable *runs* is a triple tuple...see edited response